# Why do both Java Objects return the same data

Tags: java

I have created 2 objects of the class GConveyor. I want to get some data about the objects when I select them, but both return the same information. Thanks for the help!

```
/* 
* File: DragObjects.java  
*/ 
import acm.graphics.*; 
import acm.program.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DragObjects extends GraphicsProgram { 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
// Initializes the program 
public void init() { 
    //adding a few test objects
    GConveyor conv = new GConveyor(50, 44, 120); 
    add(conv); 
    GConveyor conv2 = new GConveyor(30, 24, 60); 
    add(conv2); 

    addMouseListeners(); 
    addKeyListeners(); 
    } 

// Called on mouse press to record the coordinates of the click */ 
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 
    // GPoint has X and Y coordinate 
    last = new GPoint(e.getPoint()); 
    gobj = getElementAt(last);  
    //looking at stuff so to understand
    getObjectData ();
}


public void getObjectData (){
    //looking at stuff so to understand
    System.out.println(gobj.toString());    

    GContainer obLength = gobj.getParent();
    System.out.println(obLength.toString());    

    int d = ((GCompound) gobj).getElementCount();
    System.out.println( "Element per GConveyor:"+ d  );

    System.out.println( "hashcode:" +gobj.hashCode());

    int y = this.getElementCount();
    System.out.println( "this Element Count:"+ y  );

    int a = GConveyor.getBF();      
    System.out.println( "bf:" + a  );
    int b = GConveyor.getEF();      
    System.out.println( "ef:" + b  );
    int h = GConveyor.getLength();      
    System.out.println( "length:" + h  );
    int c = ((GConveyor) gobj).getLength();     
    System.out.println( "length:" + c  );       
}



// Called on mouse drag to reposition the object 
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { 
    if (gobj != null) { 
        gobj.move(e.getX() - last.getX(), e.getY() - last.getY()); 
        last = new GPoint(e.getPoint());
        } } 

/* Private instance variables */
private GObject gobj; 
/* The object being dragged */
private GPoint last; 

}
```

the following is my GConveyor class

```
 /* 
 * 
 * File: GConveyor.java * This class implements a conveyor as a GCompound.
 */ 

import java.awt.Color;
import acm.graphics.*; 

public class GConveyor extends GCompound {
/* Constants specifying frame size*/
private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 2;
private static int myBf;
private static int myEf;
private static int myLength;

private static final double scale = 10;
/* Private instance variables */
private GRect outer;
private GRect chain_box;
private GRect effWidth;
private GPolygon pti;
private GPolygon pto;

public GConveyor(int bf, int ef, int length) {
outer = new GRect(length, ((FRAME_WIDTH *2) + bf));
chain_box = new GRect(length , bf - ef);
effWidth = new GRect(length, bf);
pti = createAnchor(scale);
pto = createAnchor(scale);
add(outer, 0 , 0);
add(chain_box, 0 , FRAME_WIDTH);
add(effWidth, 0 , FRAME_WIDTH);
add(pti, 0 , FRAME_WIDTH + (bf-ef) + (ef/2));
add(pto, length , FRAME_WIDTH + (bf-ef) + (ef/2));

myBf = bf;
myEf = ef;
myLength = length;

}

public static int getBF(){
return myBf;
}
public static int getEF(){
return myEf; 
}
public static int getLength(){
return myLength;
}


/* Creates a hex for the Anchor */
private GPolygon createAnchor(double scale) {
GPolygon poly = new GPolygon();
poly.addVertex(-0.25*scale, 0.433*scale);
poly.addVertex(-0.5*scale, 0.0*scale);
poly.addVertex(-0.25*scale, -0.433*scale);
poly.addVertex(0.25*scale, -0.433*scale);
poly.addVertex(0.5*scale, 0.0*scale);
poly.addVertex(0.25*scale, 0.433*scale);
poly.setFilled(true);
poly.setFillColor(Color.BLUE);
return poly;
}

public String toString(){
return("" +myBf+ +myEf+ +myLength+ "");

}

}
```

Comment: GConveyor  wouldn't be a static class would it?

Comment: I have some static methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These variables are static, so these single variables (and their singular values) will be used in all instances of your `GConveyor` class. That is why you are getting the same information.

```
private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 2;
private static int myBf;
private static int myEf;
private static int myLength;
```

Eliminate the `static` keyword where you don't need them (where unique information is required in each instance), and you should be good.

Comment: `static` is probably OK for `FRAME_WIDTH`.  But not the others.

Comment: Yes. true. Leave `FRAME_WIDTH` as static.

Answer (score 2):

`myBF`, `myEF`, and `myLength` are declared `static` in `GConveyor`.  That means there is only one of each of those integers, and each one is shared by **all** objects of the class.  When you call the `GConveyor` constructor to create a second instance, the constructor sets those static fields, which then affect the values returned for the first instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `toString()` spits out `myBf` `myEf` and `myLength`, all of which are static.  That means they are properties of the class itself (`of GConveyer`), and not of instances of the class (`conv` and `conv2`), so when you call an instance's setter method for any of those, you are modifying the same variable.

You have 2 instances, but only 1 class, so you only have 1 set of those variables, not 2.

Do not make them static if you wish them to be attributed to each instance, and not to the class as a whole.